React Router: Trailing path param with decimal doesn't work
Can someone please explain why the following path doesn't work with react router 6 (BrowserRouter)
/path/1.1.1
but the following one does:
/path/1.1.1/
my route configuration is as follows. I am using declarative method i.e. useRoutes hook for defining the Routes.
const App = () => {
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <h1>Hello World</h1>
    },
    {
      path: '/app/:version',
      element: <AppUI />
    }
  ])
  return (
    <div>
      {routes}
    </div>
  )
}

const root = createRoot(document.querySelector('#app'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Whenever I am trying to hit /path/1.1.1 in Chrom, it throws error saying
Cannot get /path/1.1.1
My webpack config:
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'index.[hash].js',
  },
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3003,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: [...],
  plugins: [...], 
}

Surprisingly, it works on codesandbox:

What am I missing here ?

It's likely the case that "/path/1.1.1" is treated as the client requesting a file "1.1.1" from directory "/path" whereas "/path/1.1.1/" is treated as the client requesting the index file from directory "/path/1.1.1". The sandbox may "cheat" a little bit since you aren't really running a server there.
To avoid "confusion" I'd suggest passing the app version as a search parameter.
Example:
const App = () => {
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <h1>Hello World</h1>
    },
    {
      path: '/app',
      element: <AppUI />
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {routes}
    </div>
  )
}

Assume URL path + search "/app?version=1.1.1":
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppUI = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const appVersion = searchParams.get("version"); // "1.1.1"

  ...
};

Or encode the version in a more URL-friendly format, say replace "." characters with "_" underscore characters, converting back to using decimals in the routed component.


console.log("1_1_1".replaceAll("_", "."));



Assume URL path + search "/app/1_1_1":
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppUI = () => {
  const { version } = useParams();

  const appVersion = version.replaceAll("_", ".") // "1.1.1"

  ...
};

